# SQL Select Count with join on other table does not include the 0 count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count

I have the following database on SQL Server 2008:

Users Tables:

```
    id           Name            Country      BloodTypeId   
---------+---------------+------------+-----------------+
1            John            US            1            
2            Kate            China         1
3            Sam             US            2
4            Tom             Canada        1
5            Mike            US            1            
6            Carol           China         3
7            Daniel          US            2
8            Joseph          US            1
9            Mary            US            3            
10           Peter           China         1
```

Bloodtypes Table

```
    BloodTypeId      BloodTypename    
------------+------------------+
1                 A
2                 B
3                 O
4                 AB
```

I need an sql script that will return the number of bloodtypes in each country:
So for the above database, I need it to return:

```
    Country      BloodType     Count
---------+---------------+------------+
US               A          3
US               B          2
US               O          1
US               AB         0
China            A          2  
China            B          0
China            O          1
China            AB         0
Canada           A          1
Canada           B          0
Canada           O          0
Canada           AB         0
```

Note that when there is no userss in a country for a certain bloodtype I need it to appear with a 0 count.

**What I tried:**
I tried the following script:

```
SELECT Country, BloodTypename as BloodType, COUNT(1) as Count 
FROM Users
JOIN Bloodtypes
ON Users.BloodtypeId = Bloodtypes.BloodtypeId 
GROUP BY  Country, BloodTypename
ORDER BY Country
```

This query is giving me this result:

```
     Country      BloodType     Count
---------+---------------+------------+
US               A          3
US               B          2
US               O          1
China            A          2  
China            O          1
Canada           A          1
```

The blood types with 0 count are not appearing

I tried to use `RIGHT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT Country, BloodTypename as BloodType, COUNT(1) as Count 
FROM Users
RIGHT JOIN Bloodtypes
ON Users.BloodtypeId = Bloodtypes.BloodtypeId 
GROUP BY  Country, BloodTypename
ORDER BY Country
```

but still getting same results

How can I select what I need and include all the Bloodtypes even the one with 0 count?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get all the combination of `country` and blood types, by getting the cartesian product of them using `CROSS JOIN` then `LEFT JOIN`. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  t.country,
  t.BloodTypename,
  COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) as Count 
FROM
(
  SELECT u.country, b.BloodTypeId, b.BloodTypename
  FROM Users u 
  CROSS JOIN Bloodtypes b
)AS t
LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.BloodtypeId = t.BloodtypeId  AND t.country = u.country
GROUP BY t.country,  t.BloodTypename
ORDER BY Country DESC;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63465/13)

This will give you:

```
| COUNTRY | BLOODTYPENAME | COUNT |
|---------|---------------|-------|
|      US |             A |     3 |
|      US |            AB |     0 |
|      US |             B |     2 |
|      US |             O |     1 |
|   China |             A |     2 |
|   China |            AB |     0 |
|   China |             B |     0 |
|   China |             O |     1 |
|  Canada |             A |     1 |
|  Canada |            AB |     0 |
|  Canada |             B |     0 |
|  Canada |             O |     0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `left outer join` it  returns all rows from the left table (Users), with the matching rows in the right table (bloodtypes). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match so the count of NULL will be 0

```
SELECT Country, BloodTypename as BloodType, COUNT(1) as Count 
FROM Users LEFT OUTER
JOIN Bloodtypes
ON Users.BloodtypeId = Bloodtypes.BloodtypeId 
GROUP BY  Country, BloodTypename
ORDER BY Country
```